# Listening for repartition event?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm experimenting with the distributed map of Hazelcast to basically spread elements across several instances of the same application. The idea is that one application will be first to start up, and thus populate the map. Of course, the local key set will be the complete map.

When another instance joins the cluster, the map will be repartitioned so that both instances have about half (I would assume) of the entries of the map as their local key set.

```
Config hzConfig = new Config("hz");
HazelcastInstance hzInstance = HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(hzConfig);
IMap<Long, Long> test = hzInstance.getMap("test");
LocalListener listener = new LocalListener();
test.addLocalEntryListener(listener);
test.addPartitionLostListener(listener);
```

I thought the repartitioning would invoke the local entry listeners but apparently it does not and it in fact does not invoke any of the other listeners.

The concrete use case is that, the first application populates the map, and when the others join, the entries get spread over them, and for each entry in their local key set they must do something. Rather than periodically checking the local key set, I would rather do it upon events such as added/removed from local key set.

However, should an instance join or leave the cluster, repartitioning happens (I hope always) however I can't seem to listen for that which kind of defeats the purpose.

Using the configuration above, and the listener below, I have a test application that puts a random long into the map every 10 seconds.

```
private static class LocalListener implements EntryAddedListener<Long, Long>, EntryRemovedListener<Long, Long>,
        EntryUpdatedListener<Long, Long>, EntryEvictedListener<Long, Long>, MapClearedListener, MapPartitionLostListener {
    @Override
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<Long, Long> event) {
        LOG.info("An entry was added to the local set: {}", event.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent<Long, Long> event) {
        LOG.info("An entry was removed from the local set: {}", event.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<Long, Long> event) {
        LOG.info("An entry was evicted from the local set: {}", event.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent<Long, Long> event) {
        LOG.info("An entry was updated in the local set: {}", event.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void mapCleared(MapEvent event) {
        LOG.info("The map was cleared: {}", event);
    }
    @Override
    public void partitionLost(MapPartitionLostEvent event) {
        LOG.info("A partition was lost: {}", event);
    }
}
```

The output of the first test instance:

```
15:43:47.718 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -1012665372499231549
15:43:47.858 [hz.hz.event-4] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -1012665372499231549
15:43:57.716 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -5501878816285329759
15:43:57.717 [hz.hz.event-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -5501878816285329759
```

Then I start the second instance and it joins the cluster.

Instance 1 output:

```
INFO: [172.20.20.7]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Re-partitioning cluster data... Migration queue size: 271
15:44:12.137 [hz.hz.event-4] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -642323604672752630
jan 10, 2019 3:44:12 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.MigrationThread
INFO: [172.20.20.7]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] All migration tasks have been completed, queues are empty.
15:44:17.716 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -2929992218325845758
15:44:17.718 [hz.hz.event-2] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -2929992218325845758
15:44:27.716 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -7717112084150209257
15:44:27.717 [hz.hz.event-3] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -7717112084150209257
15:44:37.716 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -3756253634059275245
15:44:37.717 [hz.hz.event-3] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -3756253634059275245
15:44:47.716 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry 9175632974694161488
```

Instance 2 output:

```
15:44:12.131 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -642323604672752630
15:44:22.130 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -785281121378041075
15:44:22.136 [hz.hz.event-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -785281121378041075
15:44:32.130 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry 3465608643988715362
15:44:32.132 [hz.hz.event-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: 3465608643988715362
15:44:42.131 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry 1474484225334222922
15:44:42.133 [hz.hz.event-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: 1474484225334222922
15:44:47.719 [hz.hz.event-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: 9175632974694161488
15:44:52.130 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -4535267276695561636
15:44:52.131 [hz.hz.event-2] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -4535267276695561636
```

Then I close the second instance to trigger a repartition.

Instance 1 output:

```
INFO: [172.20.20.7]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Partition balance is ok, no need to re-partition cluster data... 
jan 10, 2019 3:45:03 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor
INFO: [172.20.20.7]:5701 [dev] [3.9.3] Invocations:1 timeouts:0 backup-timeouts:1
15:45:07.716 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - Adding new entry -4645280647407966219
15:45:07.716 [hz.hz.event-5] INFO com.example.playground.DistributedMapTests - An entry was added to the local set: -4645280647407966219
```

As expected, when the application is alone, it has all the entries, and when another instance joins, a repartition happens, however, the second instance is unaware that it now has more elements in the local key set until another put happens.

Additionally, when the second instance leaves, there is for some reason no repartition, so I don't know what happened to the entries it had in its local key set.

So, TL;DR: I would like to know how to listen for repartition events. Perhaps there is an alternative in Hazelcast for this kind of thing?

**UPDATE**:

From further testing, despite saying that the partition balance is ok, the entries from the one who left the cluster do get back to the other instances. I'm assuming the message means it does not need to be redistributed over the different members as there was only one remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

local entry listeners are triggered by user operations only. Repartitioning happens whenever a member is added to/removed from the cluster. And if your cluster size is still >1 then migrations will take place, which you can listen to by using
[migration listeners](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-migration-events).

OTOH if a member leaves the cluster ungracefully then remaining members will recover it's data from their own backups. That's probably what you're seeing.

However I don't understand why you need to listen to migration events and act upon them. Is it related to your business logic? Otherwise you don't need to worry about where your keys are located and just send any business logic to your cluster via using keys. Please elaborate if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes indeed, it's business logic. Each instance of the application must maintain some related things for each element in their local key set. Specifically, when the key set changes, so must the related stuff.

Comment: Alright. Then migration listeners should help in your case. Best

Answer (score 0):

Listening to a repartition event is the wrong idea. Repartitioning happens when there is a membership change. And listening for membership changes together with entry changes would cover all the events needed.