# How to listen for repartition and restoring-from-backup events on my Hazelcast distributed cache?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

- My application needs to subscribe to a large number of "topics" via a pub-sub message service.
- All "topic" names are stored as keys in a Hazelcast IMap distributed cache (with related info as values).
- When multiple instances of my application are running, I want them to split the "topics" evenly among their local caches, and subscribe/unsubscribe from the topics when these local caches are updated.
  E.g:

1. Instance 1 starts, subscribes to all the keys
2. Instance 2 starts and subscribes to half of the keys, instance 1 unsubscribes from these same keys.
3. Instance 1 goes down. Instance 2 subscribes to all the keys which instance 1 had.
   i.e I expect all topics in cache to be subscribed to by exactly 1 instance at a given time.

**Which Hazelcast Event Listener should I use for my application, such that I can listen for repartition AND restoring-from-backup events?**

I have tried the following but have had issues with all implementations:

1. MembershipListener + CountDownLatch + Comparing keys in localKeySet before & after "ClusterReadyCountDown" to subscribe/unsubscribe: this was my initial implementation, but my application is facing some serious bugs in production related to missing/duplicate subscriptions across multiple instances. I think the MembershipListener is called before redistribution occurs, so subscribing/unsubscribing messes up sometimes. Suggestions are welcome!
2. LocalEventListener: it only triggers when I explicitly do map.put()/remove(), it doesn't trigger on cache repartition/restore from backup, only on programmatic operations on the IMap
3. MigrationListener: it only triggers when a node joins or leaves "gracefully", it doesn't trigger  when a node leaves "ungracefully".

Please let me know if you need more information!

P.S, I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142327/listening-for-repartition-event) thread, which suggests the MigrationListener -- but it didn't work in my use case.

Comment: MigrationListener should help to follow such topology changes. In that listener, replicaMigrationCompleted receives event ReplicaMigrationEvent and in that event, you have source, destination and index of replica(index 0 is owner replica others are backup). For example, if source and destination is same and replica index is 0, this means you have local promotion.

Comment: @mrck Awesome! This is the solution I ended up going with. A few questions: (1) is it safe to assume I don't need to handle the "replicaMigrationFailed" event in the case of a migration failure where the backup replica is NOT lost? I would assume that the instance of the app that is still alive would receive a partition promotion event or something in response (hence fix itself) (2) In the case that the backup replica is lost alongside the primary, is it accurate that I would use a "PartitionLostListener" instead of "replicaMigrationFailed"?

Comment: For 1, yes, self healing will work. For 2, PartitionLostListener is only notified for primary copy loss. When backup is lost self-healing will create backups eventually also in this case.